# How to get id with child route in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a angular 8 application.

And I try to make a new item with routing. The link for creating a item is a child route.   And I try to get the id of the item. But every time id is null.

I have this as routing:

```
{
    path: ':dossierId',
    component: ViewComponent,
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    },
    children: [  

      {
        path: 'item/new/:dossierItemType',
        component: ItemComponent,
        resolve: {
          dossier: DossierResolver,
          dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
        }
      },
    ]
  },
```

and this is the component:

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  itemTypes = DossierItemTypeDto;
  formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
  isNew = false;
  editItemForm: FormGroup;
  dossierItemId: string;
  item: DossierItemDto;
  dossierItems: DossierItemDto[];
  dossier: DossierDto;
  globalErrors: ValidationErrors;

  constructor(private dossierService: DossierService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,
              private errorProcessor: ErrorProcessor) {

    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.dossier.id = params.id;
    });

    //this.dossier = this.route.snapshot.data.dossier;
    this.dossierItemId = this.route.snapshot.params.dossierItemId;
    this.isNew = this.dossierItemId === undefined;
    this.dossierItems = this.route.snapshot.data.dossierItems;

    if (this.isNew) {
      this.item =  {
        title: '',
        itemType: this.route.snapshot.params.dossierItemType,
        date: moment().format('Y-MM-DD'),
        createdAt: moment().format('Y-MM-DD'),
        body: '' };
    } else {
      this.item = this.dossierItems.find(i => i.id === this.dossierItemId);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editItemForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: this.formBuilder.control(this.item.title, [Validators.required]),
      itemType: this.formBuilder.control(this.item.itemType, [Validators.required]),
      date: this.formBuilder.control(moment(this.item.date, 'Y-MM-DD'), [Validators.required]),
      body: this.formBuilder.control(this.item.body, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2097152)])
    });
  }
}
```

But every time this:

```
  this.dossier.id = params.id;
```

gives `null`

So what I have to change about this?

Thank you

if I do this:

```
 this.route.firstChild.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.dossier.id = params.id;
    });
```

I already get an error when I load the component:

```
core.js:6406 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of null
    at new ItemComponent (item.component.ts:36)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.ItemComponent_Factory [as factory] (item.component.ts:140)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:6176)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:14734)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:14040)
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:23537)
    at Module.ɵɵelement (core.js:23597)
    at ViewComponent_div_1_Template (view.component.html:8)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:13997)
    at renderView (core.js:13797)
```

if I do it like this:

```
 {
    path: ':dossierId',
    component: ViewComponent,
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }
  },

  {
    path: ':dossierId/item/new/:dossierItemType',
    component: ItemComponent,
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }
  },
```

Then it works.

But I dont want that, because I want to load new item in same view and not in seperate view

```
Thank you I try that: core.js:6406 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (item.component.ts:37)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14)
    at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:81)
    at BehaviorSubject.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at new ItemComponent (item.component.ts:36)
```

Comment: There is no **id** param in your routing config :) Do you want to get **dossierId** from the activated route?

Comment: Yes, because,  this.dossier = this.route.snapshot.data.dossier; dossier is always null when component is loading

Comment: Initialise dossier: DossierDto = {} as DossierDto;

Answer (score 0):

Add `firstChild` after route:

```
this.route.firstChild.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
   this.dossier.id = params.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the **dossierId** you can get it simply as you are getting the id. Because **id** does not exist in your routing config you can not get it. Get **dossierId** in this way:-

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  this.dossier.id = params.dossierId;
});
```

And you should do this inside the `ngOnInit()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, but in reality it is a matter of playing with the routes, the parent route does not give it a component, then create another child with the empty path and here add the component, the rest remains, keep it from this way:

```
{
    path: ':dossierId',
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ViewComponent
      }
      {
        path: 'item/new/:dossierItemType',
        component: ItemComponent,
        resolve: {
          dossier: DossierResolver,
          dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
        }
      }
    ]
}
```